# How do i encrypt & decrypt data using PEM - OPENSSL, C, BIO

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, pem

The below code can successfully encrypt and decrypt my data.

```
size_t pri_len;
size_t pub_len;
char *pri_key;
char *pub_key;
char message[AES_KEY_SIZE];
char *encrypted = NULL;
char *decrypted = NULL;

int pub_exp = 37;

RSA *keyPair = RSA_generate_key(2048,pub_exp,NULL,NULL);
BIO *pri = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
BIO *pub = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
//char passwordTemp[16] = "helloworld";
//pem_password_cb();

PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey(pri,keyPair,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL);
PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey(pub,keyPair);

pri_len = BIO_pending(pri);
pub_len = BIO_pending(pub);

pri_key = (char*)malloc(pri_len + 1);
pub_key = (char*)malloc(pub_len + 1);

BIO_read(pri,pri_key,pri_len);
BIO_read(pub,pub_key,pub_len);

pri_key[pri_len] = '\0';
pub_key[pub_len] = '\0';

//generate random number to encrypt
unsigned char randNum[AES_KEY_SIZE];
this->generateRandomNum(randNum,AES_KEY_SIZE);

char *encrypt2 =(char*) malloc(RSA_size(keyPair));
int encrypt_len2;
if((encrypt_len2 = RSA_public_encrypt(AES_KEY_SIZE,randNum,(unsigned char*)encrypt2,keyPair, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING))==-1)
{
    printf("error");
}
else
{
    printf("encrypt success");
}

char *decrypt2 = (char*) malloc(RSA_size(keyPair));
if(RSA_private_decrypt(encrypt_len2,(unsigned char*) encrypt2, (unsigned char*) decrypt2,keyPair,  RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING)==-1)
{
    printf("error");
}
else
{
    printf("decrypt success");
}
```

However if i want to store my PEM file and use it later how do it use my keys again the encrypt and decrypt data?

I found the below functions to use to restore my RSA keys, however, if i use either of the keys to decrypt my data, an error will occur...

: Attempted to read or write protected memory

```
RSA *keyPair2 = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(pri,NULL,0,NULL);
RSA *keyPair3 = PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey(pub,NULL,0,NULL);

char *decrypt2 = (char*) malloc(RSA_size(keyPair2));
if(RSA_private_decrypt(encrypt_len2,(unsigned char*) encrypt2, (unsigned char*) decrypt2,keyPair2,  RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING)==-1)
{
    printf("error");
}
else
{
    printf("decrypt success");
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing the obvious, but couldn't you store them in a  file-BIO rather than a mem-BIO, and load them at-will from disk?

Answer (score 0):

You need to encrypt the keys with private key and then persist in a file. However, security of private it is important. You can consider PKCS #8 to store private key securely.